# HTML Image onload triggers onerror?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onload, onerror

I have an html image that is labeled as follow

```
   <image src = 'image.png' onerror = "handleError(this)" onload = "handleLoad(this)">

    function handleError(n){
        getFirstChild(n.parentNode).style.display = '',n.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function handleLoad(n){
        getFirstChild(n.parentNode).style.display = 'none',n.style.display = '';
    }
```

I have a separate function getFirstChild but that doesn't have anything to do with the following problem.

Basically what is happening is in IE 11 is that the onLoad handler is getting fired and my function is setting the displays correctly, however right after the onload is fired, the onerror is also fired and overwrites what the handleLoad function has done.
Sadly this application is only supported in the IE browser but its only happening in IE11 version, in IE10 this works as expected.

I'm not sure how an onLoad can trigger, and then the onError be trigger right after when the onLoad has found the image from the src.

SECOND EDIT

As the comment below shot I'm not able to reproduce this in a jfiddle on IE11. This could be because of different things my code is trying to do at the same time, but is there any way to see why the onerror handler was trigger? I tried printing out the src of the Image item but that doesn't seem to be the issue as both onError and onLoad return the same src, and the image is clearly there.
Anyway that i can see what is causing the onError to trigger?

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue, but you're missing quotes around your handlers inside the image tag.

Comment: Ah, OK, no problem. I couldn't get the error that you're describing in IE11 (Win8) with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pxx3u9om/).

Comment: @AWolf I will update question with the format structure of the HTML, when I get a chance.

Comment: You could use the IE developer tools, set a breakpoint and step through it. Clear the console when you visit the page, then refresh and check the console again. There may be an error in there...

Comment: @Tim i used the IE dev tools but there is no error generated in the console. I even monitored the network and all the responses come back without errors. I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: You don't need to pass this, it will be available to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The window.onload event is used by programmers to kick-start their web applications.IE supports a very handy (but non-standard) attribute for the  tag: defer. The presence of this attribute will instruct IE to defer the loading of a script until after the DOM has loaded. This only works for external scripts however. Another important thing to note is that this attribute cannot be set using script. That means you cannot create a script using DOM methods and set the defer attribute – it will be ignored.

Using the handy defer attribute we can create a mini-script that calls our onload handler:

```
<script defer src="ie_onload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The contents of this external script would be a single line of code to call our onload event handler:

```
init();
function init() {
// quit if this function has already been called
if (arguments.callee.done) return;

// flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
arguments.callee.done = true;

// do stuff
};
```

as we can see there are many problems associated with using DOM event handler in IE, hence conditional compilation can be one more option for OP's problem.
IMHO you should go for this link:

```
http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/09/busted/
```

Comment: This answer has completely no relationship with the question.